# how to remove current SelectedIndex item from Listbox control c# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

Please some body tell me how to remove current SelectedIndex item from Listbox control.

this is my code:....................................................................................................................................................

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.Items.Add("www.google.com");
        listBox1.Items.Add("www.facebook.com");
        listBox1.Items.Add("www.yahoo.com");
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listBox1.DataSource = listBox1.Items;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var num = listBox1.Items.Count;
        string str = Convert.ToString(num);
        textBox1.Text = str;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; )
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    //what do i do to remove current SelectedIndex item from Listbox control.
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it directly from the *Items* collection using *[RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat)*:

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

Alternatively, you can remove the *[SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem)*:

```
listBox1.items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```